# Error when using "pmset sleepnow"

Tags: macos, command-line, sleep-wake

Whenever I use `pmset sleepnow` in Terminal (even with `sudo`) I get this error:
`Unable to sleep system: error 0xe00002e2`. I have no idea what's going on. Please help!

Comment: Are you on the latest version of your firmware? [This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1945174?start=0&tstart=0) mentions that there were problems with old firmware.

Comment: I don't have any updates available in the App Store... Does that mean I have the latest firmware?

Comment: No, firmware updates don't show up on the app store. Follow [this guide.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518)

Comment: Followed it; I have the latest FW version for my model.

Comment: Afraid I don't know then, sorry.

Comment: Is there anything related in `/var/log/system.log`? Also can you please run `pmset -g assertions` and add the results to the question?

Comment: I haven't updated this in a while. My Mac is part of the Apple Management thing, and no sleep is a known issue caused by that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled with the problem for months without any luck; the computer was unable to sleep, the sleep option on the apple menu was greyed out, pmset -g assertions (the most popular suggested solution to find ongoing processes) didn't return any result, and resetting the SMC didn't work. Today I finally found the solution that worked for mine

```
sudo pmset -a disablesleep 0
```

Hope this works for others too!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  The background info is good, but the info about the solution seems to be missing.  Can you provide some details, links, or references?